# How to implement function trim using Parsec in haskell?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am learning `Parsec` and want to practice it by implementing function `trim`. Here is my code:

```
module Trim where
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding(spaces)
trim = reverse.trimFront.reverse.trimFront
trimFront :: String->String
trimFront = readExpr trimParser
readExpr :: Parser String->String->String
readExpr parser input = case parse parser "trim" input of
                             Left err -> error $ show err
                             Right val -> val
spaces = many space
trimParser :: Parser String
trimParser = spaces >> many anyChar
```

my question is, How could I implement `trim` in function `trimParser`  directly without having to implement `trimFront` first?

Comment: I'm guessing trimParser is supposed to parse any string, including strings containing spaces, ignoring trailing and leading whitespace. If so, the simplest way is really just to "parse" the string unconditionally and then apply the trim function to the result; `trim <$> many anyChar`.

Comment: It is indeed generally a very very good idea to say what it is that your code is supposed to do, instead of just dumping it on the table.

Answer (score 2):

To trim the spaces from both sides of a string:

```
trim :: String -> String
trim = dropWhileEnd isSpace . dropWhile isSpace
```

Note that you may be better off using the following implementation of `dropWhileEnd` instead of the one from `Data.List`, depending on the situation:

```
dropWhileEnd :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
dropWhileEnd p = foldr
  (\x xs -> if null xs && p x then [] else x : xs) []
```

Comment: I know how to trim from both side, I just wonder how to implement trim using `Parsec`.

Comment: That sounds like you're going to misuse Parsec. Is there a specific reason why would you want to trim using Parsec?

Comment: @Arnon First line of his question: "I am learning `Parsec` and want to practice it by implementing function `trim`."